# Can't install APK into rooted device

Tags: android, permissions, apk

I'm using IntelliJ to try deploy an APK into my smartphone (Sony Xperia Z3 compact with OS version 5.1.1 build number 23.4.A.0.580 with root). I keep receiving this message when trying to install the APK in the device:

"Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES."

Additional information:

- I have previously deployed the same APK in the same device before with a different rooted OS version (i.e version < 5.1.1).
- I have tried to deploy without success while having the permission in my manifest.

What are the possible causes for this error?

EDIT:

It seems that it has something to do with root permissions of the shell app in the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem using the app adbd Insecure.

Answer (score 1):

I have a secondary phone for testing, Samsung Galaxy Grand, and it has Cyanogenmod 12, is rooted, and I never got this error.

But, from what I can guess, add this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml, and you should be good to go.